# Fixed location of info windows

Tags: location, google-fusion-tables, fixed, infowindow

I am making a (very straightforward) map in Google Fusion Tables, with a lot of polygones close to eachother. If one opens the infowindow, it overlaps a large part of the map, which is not convenient. Therefore, I am looking for a way to open the infowindows at a fixed location, for example in the top right corner of the map.

I am new to the code behind the maps and not very familiair to Javascript, but if I understand [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#move) right, it is possible to move the info window by calling setPosition() on the info window. It would be nice to get some suggestions for the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a real fixed element instead of an infoWindow, e.g. a [custom control](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls)

Suppress the built-in infoWindow via the `suppressInfoWindows`-option of the layer.

Then observe the `click`-event of the layer and assign the `infoWindowHtml`-property of the `event` to the `innerHTML` of the control.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/eG23U/